# Kotlin - How to use a new line within a string?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have a dumb question, how can you make a new line within the string, instead of using Java, I would want to use Kotlin instead, the purpose of this is I want to make the TextView to display a certain string, but I also want to make a new line within the same string, but don't know the command as I search in the net, it doesn't show. Such as:

Java:

```
System.out.println("Hello")
System.out.println("World!")

System.out.print("Hello\n World!")
```

C#:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello")
Console.WriteLine("World!")

Console.Write("Hello\n World!")
```

Here is the code of what I am planning to do:

The method

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view)
        val longitudeText = mLocation.longitude
        val latitudeText = mLocation.latitude
        val altitudeText = mLocation.altitude

        val originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.gefvqkbbslamdpkxf1zv_bigstock_aerial_view_of_blue_lakes_and__227291596)?.let { it ->
            firstAddWatermark(
                it,
                "Longitude: ${resources.getString(R.string.value_of_7, longitudeText)}м, Latitude: ${resources.getString(R.string.value_of_7, latitudeText)}м" + "\n" +
                        "Altitude: ${{resources.getString(R.string.value_of_2, altitudeText)}}",
                WatermarkOptions(
                    Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                    textSizeToWidthRatio = 0.015f,
                    paddingToWidthRatio = 0.03f,
                    Color.RED,
                    Color.BLACK,
                    typeface = null
                )
            )
        }
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap)
    }
```

The functions:

```
private fun firstAddWatermark(bitmap: Bitmap, firstWatermarkText: String, options: WatermarkOptions = WatermarkOptions()): Bitmap {
        val result = bitmap.copy(bitmap.config, true)
        val canvas = Canvas(result)
        val paint = Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or DITHER_FLAG)
        paint.textAlign = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> Paint.Align.LEFT
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> Paint.Align.RIGHT
        }

        val textSize = result.width * options.textSizeToWidthRatio
        paint.textSize = textSize
        paint.color = options.textColor

        if (options.shadowColor != null) {
            paint.setShadowLayer(textSize / 2, 0f, 0f, options.shadowColor)
        }

        if (options.typeface != null) {
            paint.typeface = options.typeface
        }

        val padding = result.width * options.paddingToWidthRatio
        val coordinates = calculateCoordinates(firstWatermarkText, paint, options, canvas.width, canvas.height, padding)
        canvas.drawText(firstWatermarkText, coordinates.x, coordinates.y, paint)
        return result
    }

    private fun calculateCoordinates(watermarkText: String, paint: Paint, options: WatermarkOptions, width: Int, height: Int, padding: Float): PointF {
        val x = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT -> {
                    padding
                }
            Corner.TOP_RIGHT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                    width - padding
                }
        }

        val y = when (options.corner) {
            Corner.BOTTOM_LEFT,
                Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT -> {
                    height - padding
                }
            Corner.TOP_LEFT,
                Corner.TOP_RIGHT -> {
                    val bounds = Rect()
                    paint.getTextBounds(watermarkText, 0, watermarkText.length, bounds)
                    val textHeight = bounds.height()
                    textHeight + padding
                }
        }
        return PointF(x, y)
    }

    enum class Corner {
        TOP_LEFT,
        TOP_RIGHT,
        BOTTOM_LEFT,
        BOTTOM_RIGHT
    }

    data class WatermarkOptions(
        val corner: Corner = Corner.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        val textSizeToWidthRatio: Float = 0.04f,
        val paddingToWidthRatio: Float = 0.03f,
        @ColorInt val textColor: Int = Color.WHITE,
        @ColorInt val shadowColor: Int? = Color.BLACK,
        val typeface: Typeface? = null
    )
```

The result of that:
postimg.cc/75SF4v3F

Comment: well, `\n` is working in Kotlin according to [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#characters)...

Comment: there are loads and loads of resources available when you search `new line in kotlin` - are you _sure_ you didn't find anything online ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\n` in the kotlin as well.